# How to find the value of an attribute on an user object by using LDAP?

Tags: ldap, openldap, spring-ldap, ldap-query, spring-security-ldap

I'm new to LDAP and currently i have a doubt on that topic.
Please help me in this: How to perform an ldap search to find the value of "xyz" attribute on the user object "cn=testuser,dc=netmail"?

```
Given service: ldap, 
host:test.abcd.com,
baseDN:dc=abcd,
baseDN:cn=testuser,dc=abcd,
pass:qaz123.
```

Comment: By using LDAP or by using Spring-LDAP?

Answer (score 0):

Using `ldapsearch` you can do it this way:

```
ldapsearch -h test.abcd.com -b cn=testuser,dc=netmail xyz
```

If you want to use simple authentication instead of SASL to do the search:

```
ldapsearch -h test.abcd.com -x -D <binddn> -b cn=testuser,dc=netmail xyz
```